# Firefox: style sheet appears multiple times in developer tools

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-developer-tools

I have a few linked style sheets on a sample site (https://responsive.webcraft101.com/index.html). One of the links is to be toggled on and off, so it includes an `id`:

```html
<link id="sketch" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/sketch.css">
```

I jave some JavaScript on the `header` element which disables and enables the style sheet. A simplified version is:

```js
var ss = document.querySelector('link#sketch');
var header = document.querySelector('header');
header.onclick = event => { ss.disabled = !ss.disabled; } ;
```

It works well enough. However, when I look at the style sheets in Firefox’s developer tools, the `sketch.css` style sheet is added to the list every time `disabled` is set to `false`.

Does that indicate something wrong with the process? How can I stop this from happening?

**Edit**

This is the case both on my Mac with lots of addons, and on my Windows, even with addons disabled.

Comment: Looking at the dev tools in both firefox and safari, I don't see the style tag being added multiple times. When I click on the header, the `disabled` tag gets updated and only one instance is ever present. If you're not seeing multiple style tags, I don't *think* this indicates an issue. I'm on FF 103.0.2 (64-bit) macOS

Comment: I have used this method with inline styles (`<style id="someID">`) on numerous occasions without the issue you mention. Toggling the inline styles does not grow the list in the 'Style Editor'.  Makes me wonder if your method will cause memory problems/leakage with excessive toggling. Until resolved, for the time being maybe toggle the styles inline? Here's an [extensive codepen demo](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/zYPKEVL) of how I do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a bug in the Style Editor. And it looks like [it is going to be fixed in an upcoming Firefox version](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1771113).

Answer (score 0):

I can see it happening in **firefox** but not **brave**.  I am not sure if it actually has that many copies or whether it's just showing a log of as they were applied.  Personally, I wouldn't do it this way.  I think that you can do it by having one class in the body that you toggle.  I don`t think this was an intended design parameter.  **It is not a visual element.**

I have only seen this used as a way to lazy load the style sheet.  And then they add a link instead of enabling it.

[Usage Example here](https://kudadam.com/blog/lazy-loading-stylesheets-and-scripts)